# Is the only way to discover signed commit headers by parsing the entire raw commit header?

Tags: libgit2

libgit2 support extracting signatures using git_commit_extract_signature, supplying the header field as the last argument (or NULL for gpgsig).

However, for commits with the non-default gpgsig, is there any way to find out what the header of an existing signed commit, or am I resigned to parsing the full header?